Unable to load pages offline using SW - Workbox & Node.js
So I'm trying to build a very simple prototype for a website that could be displayed even when the user is offline (like a PWA i suppose)... however as a newbie I'm finding the documentation quite tedious to wrap my head around so I'd appreciate if someone could simplify and break it down to me -
I've a simple node.js server that serves 2 pages -> index.html and second_page.html both under a form respectively which allow redirects on the click of a button,
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
  });

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendFile((path.join(__dirname + '/second_page.html')));
});


and similarly for the other page too, I've a separate service-worker.js that has -
importScripts(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.4.1/workbox-sw.js'
  );

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === "document",
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    ({request})=> request.destination == "image",
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);

When I hit the URL, it inspects as the following -

I've included the scripts in my index.html page as follows -
<body>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        }
    </script>

    <h1>First Page</h1>
    <img src="/logo.png" alt="abc">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <a href=""><button>Next Page</button></a>
    </form>

</body>

However, when I try to access the website after turning off my internet, then it doesn't show up, what am I missing ?
